# While uploading file getting error as boundary not found when content-type sent as "multipart/form-data".How to solve this error?

Tags: angular

```
upload(){  

    console.log("file selected :", this.doc_upload_file);
    let filearray=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.doc_upload_file));
    console.log("................",filearray);

    console.log("form selected :", this.form);

    this.onSubmit(this.form);

  }

 this.url = this.main_url +'/entities/upload?id='+entityid+'&entityType='+entitytype+'&docType='+documenttype;
    var authorization = 'Bearer '+this.sharedService.access_token;
    const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data',"Authorization": authorization});

    return this.http.post(this.url,this.body,{headers:headers})
        .pipe(map(
            (response) => {
                // var data = response.json();
                console.log('uploadDocuments: ', response);
                console.log('status: ', response.status);
                return response.status;
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error.json());
            }
        ));
```

ERROR -

> error: "Internal Server Error" exception:
>   "org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException" message: "Could
>   not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is
>   java.io.IOException:
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the
>   request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found"

Answer (score 0):

I think you need send a FormData to solve your problem.

Somethink like this:

```
let item = event.target.files[0];
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append(item.name, item, item.name);

        ...


return this.http.post(this.url, formData ,{headers:headers})
        .pipe(map(
          (response) => {
                  ...
          },
       (error) => {
        ...
       }
));
```

Comment: I already tried the above solution but it is not useful to solve my problem.